# Woocommerce Variation Radio Button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button

I am modifying variable.php so there will be radio buttons instead of a dropdown for products with different variations. One variation is working and adding to cart properly while the other button says in "Invalid value posted for Options". Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Search as there is a plugin for that and it is something complicated to do it yourself…

Answer (score 0):

with the new version of woocommerce it seems that the value you are posting must be preset as an attribute value for that particular product. What does the ratio button have as a name and a value? does this match your product variation choices?